# How to change the font size of the abstract in KOMA-script?

Tags: fontsize, koma-script, abstract

More obviously, the following does work:

```
\addtokomafont{abstract}{\footnotesize}
```

Less obviously, the following does not work either:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\abstract}{\footnotesize}{}{}{}
```

So is it possible to change the abstract font size? If so how?

**Edit**

Here is a minimal example of my problem (based on the answer below):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\section{A Section}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

I want the abstract to appear in a smaller font size but doing so in the preamble.

Comment: Koma does not provide an `abstract` element for font purpose.

Comment: What class are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunaly there is no MWE in your question. So I can only guess what you are doing.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
%\documentclass{scrreprt}
%\documentclass[abstract]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{abstract}{\footnotesize}

\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\section{A Section}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

or

```
\documentclass[abstract]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd\abstract{\small}{\footnotesize}{}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\section{A Section}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great. I guess this provides a quite general way to change the font size of (almost?) any environment in KOMA script, right?

Comment: No, it depends on the definition of the environment.